# Visual Studio Code no reconoce mi móvil

Tags: flutter, vscode, dart, emulador

Llevo programando ya varias semanas una app y nunca había tenido el problema con el VSCode de no poder lanzar mi app a mi terminal móvil, con los Emuladores que tengo configurados no tengo problemas pero de repente ha dejado de reconocerme mi móvil y no puedo comprobar como ejecuta el código en el.
¿A alguien le ha pasado esto y lo ha podido solucionar?.
Gracias.

Comment: Te aseguraste de que no hayas desactivado la depuración por usb sin intención?

Comment: vs code no hace absolutamente nada por si mismo.. verifica las extensiones que tenes...

Comment: Son muchas las causas, puede ser hasta tu cable, por qué no revisas que mensaje se muestra, desconectalo y conectalo, agrega más información [ask]

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, como bien decís no era problema del VSCode sino del teléfono, solo tuve que volver a configurar el modo desarrollador y volvió a reconocerlo.
Gracias chicos!!